# Tie a process to specific CPU cores

Tags: linux, process, debian

I have a Debian server with software-RAID and a quad-core processor. Once all cores are under full load, the RAID system has a huge IO delay.

The server is running some very CPU-expensive jobs.

Is it possible that I can tie these jobs to specific cores so I can reserve one core for RAID?

Comment: for future googling, try looking up "affinity".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `taskset` to do this. I doubt that it will make much difference though.

[$ man taskset](http://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why do you think it doesn't make much difference if I reserve one core for everything *except* these jobs? The jobs don't access the disks, they just hit the cpu very hard.

Comment: The kernel is already pretty good at figuring out what CPU cores to use for tasks. Second-guessing it with `taskset` usually leads to worse results.

Comment: @duskwuff: absolutely - that's why I said that I doubt that it will make much difference. I have encountered particular cases where it helps though, so it's worth trying, even if it turns out not to yield any benefit.

Comment: @Philip: as duskwuff says, Linux already does a pretty good job of managing CPU affinity, but it's easy enough to try using taskset to see if it helps, so I would still try it.

Comment: I've tied the jobs to the first 3 cores so core number 4 has no load. I am seeing a improvement. The software raid works the way it should and other processes can continue while the first 3 cores are basically locked. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great - glad it helped in your case.